# jquery post, clear this form

Tags: jquery, post, this

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/4q284h96/1/

```
    $(function(){

        $('button').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

              $.post(TheAjax.ajaxurl, classData).done(function(result){       
                if(result == 'success') {
                  $('.classForm [type=text]', this).val('');
                  $('.class-form-message').append('<p>Thank You</p>');
                }
              }, 'jsonp');
            }  
          })
        })
    })
```

I have a number of sepearate forms on a page that will be partly prefilled.

The forms are validated then I'm using post to send the data to a php mail function.

When the result is success I would like to empty just the form that has been filled.

The function to empty the form is coming from the post function I can't empty just 'this' form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `submit` event instead of the `click` event. Then `this` inside the handler will be the `form`. Save the reference to the form in the handler to a variable:

```
var form = $(this);
```

Because in post `success` `this` is the `window` object. Then use the variable `form` to target the form inside `success`.

```
$('.classForm:text', form).val('');
```